# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath

I created a form in Infopath 2013 and published.
I created a Workflow in SP 2013 designer.
I want to update a field in the form by using update item action but when I select current item, none of the fields from my form are there to select.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Randy

Comment: are you correctly bind the workflow to document library ( or list) that your infopath previously published ??

Comment: And did you set form fields as columns during form publishing , which make them available to edit?

Answer (score 0):

I've always found this strange (perhaps just the wording) but I belive you'll need to have this tick box selected if you want to allow a workflow to write to the field in the form.

[image]

You can then just use "Update Item" and select the field or just the "Set Field in Current Item" action to update the value.

Hope this helps!